# How to reply to an email from a student who wants a reply instantly?

Tags: teaching, email, correspondence

I have a student who wants me to reply to his emails as soon as he sends them! For example:

> I already provided you with .... form in our first meeting. Can you fill the necessary boxes and sign .... to confirm my project? ... It has already been a day, and you have not replied.

My reply:

> Thank you for sharing this information. Please find attached the document.
>
> However, it is important to note that even if you already provided me with the documents. You should give me at least 3 to 4 working days to reply to your email. It is important that you understand that there are other issues an academic has to deal with, and patience would be really appreciated.

Is there anything wrong with this response? If so, could you please help me understand how to reply to such emails?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123465/discussion-on-question-by-rsc05-how-to-reply-to-an-email-from-a-student-who-want). Please read [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/20058) before posting another comment. We can only move comments to chat once.

Answer (score 114):

Two words: "Office hours."

I say to students that, if they need immediate feedback, then they should come to my office hours, everything else will be processed as its turn arises.

[During the pandemic, of course, the office hours would be virtual]

Comment: Well, that's ok in general, but office hours are typically, say, once a week; and the student in OP's question is asking for something to happen by the next day. So the two words don't quite cover it.

Comment: @einpoklum Exceptions and emergency treatment should always be an option, that goes without saying. But it is the burden of the requester to request it and to formulate a reasonable justification. There was no mentioning or justification for the urgency in above students' mail, so I do not see a reason to change my response. OP's response is perfectly polite, but my answer suggests a practicable replacement that caters for by far most cases and, additionally, without needing to comment on their manners or being unnecessarily obstructive, defanging the commandeering edge of their demand.

Comment: I used to have a colleague with a sign on his wall that said "*lack of preparation on your part doesn't constitute an emergency on my part*"; I can't help but wonder if the student is largely the architect of the need for speed, here, because if (s)he is, then I see no reason at all their "*needs*" should be accommodated.

Comment: @MadHatter "If you dug yourself into a hole, stop digging" - "Don't compound a blunder by being rude about it." - "Sometimes rudeness conceals weakness. More often, however, it reveals a history of getting away without ever having to pay the true cost of it."

Comment: Would you really fill out forms in your office hour? And other people are waiting to get their turn? Doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes, I would. If it is so quick that they expect an immediate turnaround, then it can be done there. If not, they cannot expect an immediate turnaround. It has the additional side effect that they learn to appreciate the time it takes. Furthermore, everyone of my students knows that I will give them their due and absolutely undivided attention and doing my very best to address whatever problem they have during my office hours and they are thus happy to wait patiently for their turn.

Answer (score 59):

I see nothing wrong with your reply, it's courteous and points out what rubbed you (rightly) the wrong way. It's a good approach if you want to be professional.

In your shoes, I'd have taken twice as long as it usually takes me to finish whatever job the pushy student wants from me, while ignoring any emails during that time (except for - maybe - 'Working on it."). What the professional reply doesn't address - and it would be hard to address in such a reply - is that the formulation of the student's email is arrogant and self-centered. "It has already been a day..." Really? All things considered and the current climate of the educational system taken into account, you did just right. But someone should teach your student that the world doesn't revolve around them.

Comment: "In your shoes, I'd have taken twice as long as it usually takes me to finish whatever job the pushy student wants from me"... that's unprofessional, childish, and kinda passive aggressive, no?

Comment: @JeffC it's teaching the lesson that the student is not in charge of educational resources and that there is a varying amount of time things can take and it's typically not for them to determine the priority of certain tasks; they also need to learn that pushy behaviour does not even miss to have the desired effect but has negative effects for them, so trying to be pushy and checking when and with whom it works is not something that is worth doing. I might have given him a single warning beforehand, but sometimes you need to clearly signal that misbehaviour has a cost.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I 100% agree that the student is wrong and needs to be taught that they are not the center of the universe. This is just not the way to do that. See pretty much every other answer on how to do that properly and professionally.

Comment: I agree with @JeffC here.  Replying deliberately slowly doesn't teach any lesson at all, it just escalates the situation to no benefit.

Comment: @Jeff Something seems familiar somehow... :)

Comment: Yeah, this is pointless. It's not like the student is going to know that you did all this extra stuff to deliberately respond slowly.

Comment: Signalling that misbehaviour has a cost doesn't mean *creating* a cost. If the way you teach "actions have consequences" is by intentionally creating a consequence, then the student may well learn that it was *your* action which had a consequence for them.

Comment: Professional life is often just an endless stream of todos, with varying importance and urgency, and asked with varying degree of politeness. Those tasks must be sorted anyway, so I see no problem in not putting impolite requests in front of the queue. It's not like gnome was proposing to slack off in order to delay all the tasks.

Comment: There is some merit to this answer when combined with others; you send a clearer message by politely but sternly informing the student that their message is highly inappropriate, *after a day or two*. Replying immediately goes against the very message you are trying to get across.

Comment: The student might just be eager and has poor communication skills - even a disability. Don't assume arrogance and self centeredness. They need an education, not a rebuke.

Comment: @JeffC I upvoted quite a few other answers, too, for me this is a good practical teaching option in combination with the others (hence the "giving a warning first" or alternatively explaining in addition). Some people learn when you're polite some only when they see practical effects for themselves and not only get told how things work but shown, i.e. I think no answer (well 19 hours ago, didn't check them all again yet) covered all the bases and for me this is one method in covering them all.

Comment: @FrankHopkins ? If you take gnome's advice, you haven't taught the impatient student anything. They don't know that you made them wait because they were rude, they just know you took several days to respond. The bulk of the actionable instructions in this answer is, "I see nothing wrong with your reply, it's courteous and points out what rubbed you (rightly) the wrong way. It's a good approach if you want to be professional." which is just confirming what OP already did. Is that really useful?

Comment: @Servaes I kinda disagree with you. Responding immediately/promptly but stating that the impatient student's task will be properly prioritized with existing tasks and to expect an answer in a few days shows them YOU are a professional but will not be dictated to by a student that needs to learn patience.

Comment: @JeffC making sure to take several days for the full answer is what we are talking about as that is what you addressed in your initial comment. And my point is that that can be a good way to make sure the student actually sees that pushy mails don't speed up answers, because you make sure it takes as long as your "usual" response times. Otherwise a lesson someone can take from that is "prof may be whiney about it,but I got my answer pronto like I wanted, seems like an approach that works". I'm not saying that it is always necessary or that one couldn't improve the wording.

Comment: @JeffC but in contrast to your initial assessment as childish, unprofessional etc. it can have a teaching value. I've already said that it's likely this can be improved on - as in should not stand alone (which it also wouldn't given OP's original reply that is assumed in this answer in addition) - but so can other answers.

Comment: @FrankHopkins No, that's not what I said. Taking a few days because you have other priority tasks is fine. Making them wait **longer** (as gnome indicated) doesn't teach anything and IS childish, etc. I seriously doubt this student knows how long an email should "normally" take from this prof. I would respond immediately with a quick email stating, "Thanks. I should have an answer back to you in a couple days." and go from there but that's me and this is not my answer.

Comment: @JeffC gosh, the original answer indicates the "normal" (a couple days). It's fine if it's not your answer, but it's not objectively childish either - as I guess most here don't want to primarily do that out of spite but to make sure the student gets the message. Anyhow, we seem to have come to an common non-understanding and this turns into chat, so have a nice day/night etc.

Answer (score 44):

I feel like you're doing the student a disservice by being so polite in response to an unprofessional email.

It's not necessarily your job (unless you're a business professor maybe?) to teach email etiquette, but sending an arrogant-sounding email like that demanding faster attention may absolutely harm that student in the future.  If you reply politely, will they send a similar email to a professor who won't behave professionally in response to an email like that?  To an interviewer for a job after graduation?  To a co-worker, or someone they hope to collaborate with?  To their boss after they have a job?

I would probably word my reply a bit more sternly:

"Thank you for sharing this information. Please find attached the document.

Also, please note that the tone of your follow-up email was highly inappropriate. Keep in mind for the future that professional etiquette requires patience, and follow-up message should be worded politely."

Comment: I do not like to chastise people for manners. A one-off may be attributable to excitement or nervousness. A repeat occurrence (or a seriously rude first message) may encounter a more sardonic response, and usually people pick up on that and become polite. When they don't, castigating them for bad manners can invite them to turn the argument around and accuse you of bad manners in turn (yes, indeed! Serially rude people can be completely oblivious). You definitely do not want to go there. This attack is not easy to counter effectively, most certainly not by the tempting "appeal to authority".

Comment: What happens when you then hear about the mental health issues of the student and how you harmed them with this reply? I feel an academic has to be much more cautious these days.

Comment: @Anush That's why I suggest a one-off can be overlooked. However, mental health issues are not an excuse to treat other people rudely - this is often mentioned in discussions about people on the spectrum. There are very polite and pleasant people on the spectrum; some need to learn it, fair enough, and in this case, Jeff's response is to the point.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I don't disagree but in my experience the university will regard your offence of "insulting the student" as exponentially worse than any offence that the student could be guilty of, especially if they claim a mental health issue.

Comment: @Anush The suggested response is a polite (though stern) notification that the students message was inappropriate, and I would stand by such a message myself. The mere fact that you fear repercussions for correcting a students misbehavior is deeply concerning, and I'd get out of such an environment ASAP. If one cannot point out mistakes to ones students, then what is left for a teacher to do?

Comment: @Servaes We live in a world that takes "democracy" to the extreme. To some extent that is quite a good development. The downside is that people (especially those without benefit of education in manners themselves) are very quick to turn the argument around. One needs to be more sophisticated than merely pointing out bad manners - it really doesn't work anymore when people do not have a common ground what good manners actually are. "Good manners", for some, is "treating them well, while they can afford to treat others badly". The educational process to change that I feel is beyond our remit.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I agree entirely, and I especially appreciate that you point out that their lack of manners is likely to cost them at some point. Including this fact in the reply, in a constructive manner, gives the student an incentive to change their behavior.

Comment: @Servaes well.. I don't disagree.

Comment: Also this approach is potentially dangerous if the student happens to be mentally ill in a way that could lead them to violence (rare, but it happens).

Comment: @bob That seems silly to me.  By this logic, it would be dangerous to give that person a bad grade too.

Comment: But grading is part of the job description; it's debatable whether giving communication advice/correction is. My argument is that the former is worth taking risk; the latter isn't (at least not IMHO in our world of frequent mass shootings).

Comment: I like what you've written, but let's be honest, she's in no position to lecture the student on professionalism if she thinks that "four working days" is a reasonable response time in any professional context (aside from maybe academia).

Comment: @NeilG Well, yes, "aside from academia" because we're talking about academia.  Response times are slow in academia because there are far more students who need things than professors teaching their classes.

Comment: Telling them their email was inappropriate is likely to make them defensive (and thus not receptive to feedback) and might not be specific enough if they sincerely don't know what's rude about their email (which is not unlikely if they decided to send it in the first place). I would suggest being more specific, avoiding generic "bad" words like "inappropriate" that don't really explain the problem in any way and telling them what they should be doing instead (in more specific terms than "be polite and have patience").

Comment: What you say is undoubtedly true, but since the days of tutors standing "in loco parentis" are long past it's hardly an academic's role to instil in a student the courtesy he should have learnt somewhat earlier in life. I look forward to his persisting with the same attitude when applying for jobs, or when representing his employer to potential customers.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd While I agree that teaching manners is not any longer in a prof's job description, I think that if there is a way of instilling in the student an impression that they may get better results with more respectful interaction, it would be a win. After all, the purpose of university is about having someone guiding you not only towards constructive routes, but also away from less constructive ones. If that advice is welcomed.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I can assure you that I agree. But at the same time I'm of an age such that, when I went to university, staff and establishment were regularly criticised for behaving as though the age of majority had not been reduced (in the UK) to 18 a small number of years earlier. In that context, no matter how much I'd do my best to help out in practice, I hope that people will excuse a measure of "you've made your bed, now lie in it" when encountering a young adult who's never been taught the courtesy that goes with the privilege.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd How true. However, I find that for a very large proportion of the student population being quite strict, but at the same time thoroughly fair, is surprisingly well accepted. As I am not in favour of authoritarianism, there is a very fine balance one must strike here, but it turns out that even rowdy students suddenly start behaving civilly. I increasingly believe Socrates dictum that  - certainly not all, but by far most - people want to be good and just do not know how.

Answer (score 23):

In the future, you could tell the students at the start of term that it may take several days to reply to emails, and that if there is something urgent they should speak to you right after class or during office hours.  This should still work during the pandemic when all is online.

Comment: Yes, a predictability helps.

Answer (score 23):

I think your original reply is much better than what some others have suggested here.

- You responded with the information requested with a cool head.
- You explained that the student's tone came off as rude, and why.
- You encouraged empathy.
- You gave a concrete rule of thumb of how many days to expect from professors in the future.

Maybe the student was rude due to entitlement and impudence, maybe it was poor social skills, maybe it was a disability as suggested elsewhere. Either way, there's no need to get aggressive about it to "teach them a lesson." That is bad advice. It is better to simply be corrective, especially if this is not an ongoing issue.

Comment: I agree with you that there's no need to get aggressive about it to "teach them a lesson."

Answer (score 20):

It's funny because I just dealt with this last week (student complaining they don't see a grade listed online 38 minutes after the due date for a week-long project). I fired off a response somewhat peeved and off-kilter (and also one-handed with my cat on me), and a few minutes later somewhat regretted that I'd let my emotion show a bit.

The best thing in these cases is to be super cool, give minimal information, and don't let it be visible that they got to you. (That can possibly be used against you later in future interactions.) What I *should* have said was:

> Note that the syllabus (p. 1) says, "Contact by email is preferred;
> replies are usually sent in one day."

Adjust to taste, of course. But I don't mind having an average expectation like that documented on my syllabus.

Comment: +1, but check if there is an institutional or department policy saying what response time a student should expect, and if so state that (if not, consider asking for one to be made). Also, better to write "working day" instead of "day", to avoid giving the impression that you will also answer emails on weekends and holidays.

Comment: @kaya3: Good note for others. In my case, I do answer on weekends & holidays.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think you even owe him an apology. The students must be aware that delays of days in answers are perfectly acceptable. If you feel guilty for such an answer I'd suggest Cal Newport's book [A World Without Email](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/54326146-a-world-without-email), where he argues that people should not be "enslaved" by having to answer emails all day long.

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me was ignoring the inappropriate parts. Check the student's name to be sure you didn't promise to get back to them ASAP, check there's no new information in the email that needs to be jotted down with your other notes or where-ever. Then go back to work.

The time it takes to write back that you aren't going to write back isn't worth it. I also have no special expertise in teaching communication skills. And I've found that often students are embarrassed at what they wrote. They get nervous and spiral-out about a project and write a demanding email just to be doing something.

Alternately, if you have time, go ahead and do it. If MaryBeth is really excited about starting the project this weekend, why not help her? It won't take any more of your time to do it now than when you were planning on doing it. But, again, not worth it to comment on the crazy/rude parts.

Answer (score 6):

As well as the other answers, I think a sentence along the lines of "If there is a specific deadline for requests, include that deadline in both the subject matter and body of the email so that I can see it immediately"

Comment: I suggest wording like "if your request is time-sensitive, ..." rather than saying "deadline". Students do not get to set deadlines for their lecturers, and it would be better not to give them the impression that they are allowed to set a deadline for you. The difference is that if something is "time-sensitive" for the student, then the consequences of not receiving a response in time are bad for them, not bad for you.

Answer (score 5):

I receive such e-mails, too. Of course if there is a deadline the students have to observe themselves, I try to answer as soon as possible.

But if there is no such deadline, this behavior is simply childish. Similar to a three-year-old who thows tantrums because they want an ice-cream NOW. In this case, I treat them like a mother would treat a stubborn three-year-old: I keep calm and just ignore their complaints. I send them what they want within a few days, at a time *when it is ok for me*, with a short, polite e-mail, but I do not apologize or refer to their complaints in any other way.

I think it is important to consider the learning effect: If students are successful when they put you under pressure, they will do it again and again. If they learn that they get what they have asked for, but it is you who sets the pace, they will stop sooner or later.

Besides, think of your role at university. The university expects you to teach all students and to do some research work. This means that your time is limited, and you have to set priorities. The university is your boss, not the students, so do not allow them to be bossy with you.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's best to set a clear expectation for stuff like how quickly you'll reply to emails and what the best way to get in touch with you is in advance. For example, if you have the student in question in a course, this could be stated in the syllabus and/or on the first day of class. This is particularly the case if you have a heavy teaching or research schedule, or if it's a large class. (This applies both to academia and industry by the way).

If you don't set that expectation up front, people will likely expect whatever they're used to getting from other professors (or what you've done in the past). The student in question may simply be used to other professors replying the same day (or you may have replied to their previous emails the same day, in which case they'd expect you to continue this).

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would ignore such an email and after a few days send a mail to the student saying something like: "I seem to remember you has a request for me. Can you remind me of what it was?" Puts the student back in the right place in the food chain.

Answer (score -3):

This is Academia where pupils are to be taught. Your noting of their ridiculous demand was apt, but next time a simple "I refer your to my syllabus" (where you have properly set-up the pupil-Academic dynamic) will be quicker and deliver your message more clearly.

Comment: Obligatory (PHDcomics strip)(https://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1583). And if the students are there to be taught (I would argue they are instead there to learn!), why not teach them some workplace skills as well?

Answer (score -11):

I don't understand people who do not reply to emails. It is normal to be able to reply in 24hours. If there is something that you have to work on you can send an email like I received the email and I will check and reply within a ...say specified time. I ve  seen a lot of busy academics replying almost imeediately, in a day and lot o doing nothings all day replying in 5 days not to say not at all. Unless someone is really sought after, meaning very popular, very busy, too many grants, a lab o 20 people some companies, I don't see any reason why one cannot reply within 24 hours.

Comment: If you don't understand why someone behaves a certain way, it might be worth asking/listening to them about why, and considering how their perspective is different from yours. When you have a lot of simultaneous responsibilities, any time you spend on one means a longer wait for everything else.

Comment: @oknow, it’s been well over 24 hours. Why have you not replied to Bryan?

Comment: How many hundreds or thousands of emails do you receive in a day?